# Style css code for specific carousel

Tags: css, carousel

I have two carousels, however I want only the second carousel get the css code that is in the style tag. The first carousel should not get the tag style. I'm not able to isolate the css code to influence only the second carousel. Could someone help me? Thank you!!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-3.0.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-3.0.2/css/bootstrap.css">
    <style type="text/css">
         .carousel-control           { width:  4%; }
         .carousel-control.left,.carousel-control.right {margin-left:15px;background-image:none;}
         .carousel-inner .active.left { left: -25%; }
         .carousel-inner .next        { left:  25%; }
         .carousel-inner .prev       { left: -25%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!--first carousel-->
    <div class="container" id="carousel">
        <div id="controlar_carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#controlar_carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#controlar_carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#controlar_carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li data-target="#controlar_carousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            </ol>

            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="item active"><img src="img/1.jpg" alt=""></div>
                <div class="item"><img src="img/2.jpg" alt=""></div>
                <div class="item"><img src="img/3.jpg" alt=""></div>
                <div class="item"><img src="img/4.jpg" alt=""></div>
            </div>  

            <a href="#controlar_carousel" class="left carousel-control" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span>
            </a>

            <a href="#controlar_carousel" class="right carousel-control" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Próximo</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--second carousel-->
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center"><h3>Product Carousel</h3></div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-type="multi" data-interval="3000" id="myCarousel">
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/e499e4/fff&amp;text=1" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/e477e4/fff&amp;text=2" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/eeeeee&amp;text=3" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f4f4f4&amp;text=4" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f566f5/333&amp;text=5" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f477f4/fff&amp;text=6" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/eeeeee&amp;text=7" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/fcfcfc/333&amp;text=8" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.carousel[data-type="multi"] .item').each(function(){
          var next = $(this).next();
          if (!next.length) {
            next = $(this).siblings(':first');
          }
          next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

          for (var i=0;i<2;i++) {
            next=next.next();
            if (!next.length) {
                next = $(this).siblings(':first');
            }

            next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
          }
        });
     </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your carousel css styles a bit more specific :

```
.product-carousel .carousel-control {
    width: 4%;
}

.product-carousel .carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
    margin-left: 15px;
    background-image: none;
}

.product-carousel .carousel-inner .active.left {
    left: -25%;
}

.product-carousel .carousel-inner .next {
    left: 25%;
}

.product-carousel .carousel-inner .prev {
    left: -25%;
}
```

And in the html, just add the class `.product-carousel` as a parent of the second carousel, but not as a parent of the first. Like that :

```
<!--second carousel-->
<div class="col-md-12 text-center">
    <h3>Product Carousel</h3>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 product-carousel">
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your attention.
I made the suggested changes, but it does not work, the first carousel this good, however the second carousel got strange behavior

Comment: The styles defined in the head tag are now applied only to the second carousel, which was the purpose of the question. You probably have some styling issues. Try to post a fiddle which reproduce the problem and describe what is the 'strange behavior'. Ideally, in another question.

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrapper id that can be used for good:

```css
#myCarousel .carousel-control {
  width: 4%;
}
#myCarousel .carousel-control.left,
#myCarousel .carousel-control.right {
  margin-left: 15px;
  background-image: none;
}
#myCarousel .carousel-inner .active.left {
  left: -25%;
}
#myCarousel .carousel-inner .next {
  left: 25%;
}
#myCarousel .carousel-inner .prev {
  left: -25%;
}
```